# Why are the faces blurred and names bleeped in The Conspiracy (2012)?

Tags: the-conspiracy

The film [*The Conspiracy* (2012)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2330322) is a faux-documentary style horror film which deals with two film makers who start by making a film about a conspiracy nut and eventually turns into an exposé on an elite group of powerful world leaders.

What is strange to me about the film though is, its presented as an exposé, yet throughout the film all the names of people involved in the Tarsus Club are bleeped out and the faces in the hidden camera scenes are blurred out. If its an exposé then why take these steps to hide the identities of those involved?

Comment: Even producers of exposes can be worried about getting sued.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the premise of your question: If this were a real exposé, then the names and faces shouldn't be blurred or disguised.

However, this is fiction. By blurring the faces and garbling the voices, the audience starts to "fill in the blanks" with companies, organizations, and people they think are secretly evil / controlling. That can make the faux documentary feel more impactful and scary.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I still wonder if there is an in-universe reason for it though.

Comment: @sanpaco I'm also curious about an in-universe reason. I can't think of one, but maybe somebody else can.